# Prove using Rouche's theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

$0<|x|<1$, $n>0$ then $(z-1)^ne^z = x$ has n solu in halfplane $\text{Re}(z) > 0.$

I started make $f(z)$ $=$ $(z-1)^n$$e^z-x$ and  $g(z)$ $=$ $e^z-x$. Is it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably best to compare $(z-1)^n e^z - x$ to a function that you know has $n$ zeroes on the right-hand half-plane.

Can we think of a function that looks similar to $(z-1)^n e^z - x$, and definitely has $n$ zeroes on the right-hand half-plane? How about $(z-1)^n e^z$? This clearly has an $n$th order zero at $z = 1$, and no other zeroes.

So we should try to prove that the number of zeroes of $(z-1)^n e^z - x$ in the right-hand half-plane (counted with multiplicitiy) is the same as the number of zeroes of $(z-1)^n e^z$ (counted with multiplicity) in the right-hand half-plane.

To prove this, let $C_R$ be the semicircular contour:
$$ C_R = \{ -it_1 : t_1 \in [-R, R]  \} \cup \{ R \exp(it_2) : t_2 \in [-\tfrac \pi 2 , \tfrac \pi 2] \}. $$
It suffices to show that, for $R$ sufficiently large, the number of zeroes of $(z-1)^n e^z - x$ in the semicircular region bounded by $C_R$ is the same as the number of zeroes of $(z-1)^n e^z$ in the same semicircular region.

By Rouche's theorem, it is enough to show that $|x| < |(z-1)^n e^z |$ along the contour $C_R$, for sufficiently large $R$. This should be possible to achieve, provided you make $R$ big enough, since $|x| < 1$ by assumption.

I'll hope you can fill in the details; don't hesitate to ask questions if this isn't clear.